# Logstash / Elasticsearch: Number format exception for geoip.asn value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Trying to parse and use in another field the `geoip.asn` value as follows:

```
   geoip {
    default_database_type => "ASN"
    source => "dst"
   }

   mutate {
    add_field => { "[dst_asn]" => "%{[geoip][asn]}" }
    # remove_field => [ "geoip" ]
   }
```

Here is my respective index template field declaration:

```
"dst_asn": {"type": "integer"},
```

However, for **some** values I get the following error:

```
[2018-11-07T14:19:17,716][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"my_index_raw_data-2018.11.07", :_type=>"_doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x5c30a50a>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"my_index_raw_data-2018.11.07", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"Kcsc7mYBo99I6PWl0CVS", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [dst_asn]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"%{[geoip][asn]}\""}}}}}
```

_

```
# sudo dpkg -s logstash
Package: logstash
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: default
Installed-Size: 253337
Maintainer: <vagrant@packer-virtualbox-iso-1522340558>
Architecture: all
Version: 1:6.4.2-1
Conffiles:
 /etc/logstash/jvm.options 762ae825205c9b1b2716093895b25022
 /etc/logstash/log4j2.properties cf74034ff061d473fee9dc1c7eb07d16
 /etc/logstash/logstash-sample.conf 4ef421e7ee74e023c9b07f200cc6010a
 /etc/logstash/logstash.yml 41cb35d7b75bf4b76215b1ad393e6a5c
 /etc/logstash/pipelines.yml f4fec5524ff51ccd6a5e7f686cb8c3f5
 /etc/logstash/startup.options 63ffc442d4f1c1a56c178a1d8af85eb0
Description: An extensible logging pipeline
License: Elastic-License
Vendor: Elasticsearch
Homepage: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/

root@atlantis-server:/usr/share/logstash# bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose | grep geoip
logstash-filter-geoip (5.0.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_field` definition is not correct, it should be like this:

```
add_field => { "[dst_asn]" => "%{[geoip][asn]}" }
```

Comment: I had already fixed this (updated my question also) but still getting the `number_format_exception` for __some__ documents;

Comment: You didn't update as per my answer. Check the syntax correctly ;-)

Comment: Yes you were right; fixed both my `logstash` config and my question, however I still get the exact same error;

Comment: Can you add `stdout {codec => rubydebug}` in your output section and show a sample event that gets logged?

Comment: [2018-11-07T15:41:42,090][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"my_index_raw_data-2018.11.07", :_type=>"_doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x2b24fc1f>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"my_index_raw_data-2018.11.07", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"C8No7mYB1e9qUCtIQuRE", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [dst_asn]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"%{[geoip][asn]}\""}}}}}

Comment: The problem is obviously related to `_geoip_lookup_failure` and the `geoip.asn` not being retrieved, in which case it tries to parse as integer the value `%{[geoip][asn]}`. The weird is that e.g. this happened for an ip (`45.60.76.225`) that seems to __do__ have an asn: https://www.ultratools.com/tools/asnInfoResult?domainName=45.60.76.225 which seems to be AS19551; Could it be the `logstash` geoip is outdated?

Comment: Which version of Logstash do you have ? Also can you run this `bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose | grep geoip`, what version of the geoip plugin do you get?

Comment: updated my answer; could it also be our corporate firewall issue? however for several other IPs I do manage to get the `asn`

Comment: This is the ASN DB used in the geoip plugin: https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2-asn-csv-database/

Comment: There we go. In that case, what you should do to prevent the error is to only add the field if it exists.

Comment: thx. I added the relevant field existence check before proceeding and doing anything with it;